# My binded Label is not changed [INotifyPropertyChanged]

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I recently started learning Xamarin and I stumbled across the following problem. I have a single label in my XAML file which is bound to a ViewModel property. I am using the ICommand interface to bind a tap gesture to a method in my ViewModel which is supposed to update the label's text. However, it is not updating the "Please touch me once!". I am just wondering what I am doing wrong here?

MainPage xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
         x:Class="App1.MainPage">

<Label Text="{Binding MessageContent, Mode=TwoWay}"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnLabelTouchedCmd}" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>

</Label>

</ContentPage>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _messageContent;

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        MessageContent = "Please touch me once!";

        OnLabelTouchedCmd = new Command(() => { MessageContent = "Hey, stop toutching me!"; });
    }

    public ICommand OnLabelTouchedCmd { get; private set; }

    public string MessageContent
    {
        get => _messageContent;
        set
        {
            _messageContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(value);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling [OnPropertyChanged](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged/) with a wrong argument as seen here:

```
protected virtual Void OnPropertyChanged ([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName)
```

It expects the name of the property instead of the value you're passing now. Try this instead:

```
public string MessageContent
{
    get => _messageContent;
    set
    {
        _messageContent = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("MessageContent");
    }
}
```

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you! I thought I should provide the new value of the changed property but it is supposed to be the property itself that is being changed.

Answer (score 1):

## Explaination

The current code isn't working because it is passing the `value` of the property into `OnPropertyChanged`.

Instead, we need to pass the name of the property as a `string` into `OnPropertyChanged`.

## Answer

We can take advantage of the `CallerMemberName` attribute to make the code more concise and to avoid hard-coding strings when calling `OnPropertyChanged`.

Adding `[CallerMemberName]` to the parameter of `OnPropertyChanged` allows you to call `OnPropertyChanged()` from the setter of the property, and the property name is automatically passed into the argument.

### Updated Method

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

## Updated ViewModel

```cs
class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _messageContent;

    ...

    public string MessageContent
    {
        get => _messageContent;
        set
        {
            _messageContent = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the ViewModelBase located [here](https://pastebin.com/aLMXRN50), have all your ViewModels inherit from it. You can call just OnPropertyChanged, in either of the two ways below. The first of which will just take the name of the calling member, in this case your public property.

```
OnPropertyChanged();

OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
```

Edit- this is in extension to Brandon's correct answer